# Call a webview inside another webview in android?

Tags: android, html, load, webview

I have a custom html(suppose a.html) file which i am using from the resources and thus building a string with the entire document which is then passed to the WebView.

There's some text in a.html on click of which i want load another file b.html in the webview itself.

Please let me know what is the apporach to be followed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Implement a `WebViewClient`, overriding `shouldOverrideURLLoading()`.

Step #2: In `shouldOverrideURLLoading()`, load what you want -- this will be called on link clicks and redirects, and you are supplied the URL that ordinarily would be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now i am not able to handle the back button on this screens, currently my parent class has this piece of code `if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && helpView.canGoBack()) { helpView.goBack(); return true; }`

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)() then you can have the link loaded into the current WebView by returning false.